# Segmentation Fault constructor with QWidget. Qt/C++

Tags: c++, qt, segmentation-fault, qwidget

I have this problem.
Sometimes (but very rarely) my program crash on starting. 
The QDebugger points to the segmentation fault originating from this code:

```
view_add_bagagli::view_add_bagagli(QWidget*parent):QWidget(parent),setBagWid(new QWidget_add_lug(this)),
setPropWid(new QWidget_add_owner(this)),
setViaWid(new QWidget_add_travel(this)){} // segm fault at this line
```

And this is the code of QWidget_add_travel 's constructor:

```
QWidget_add_travel::QWidget_add_travel(QWidget *parent) : Qwidget(parent),via_l(new QVBoxLayout()){
    setLayout(via_l);
    build();
}
```

But QDebugger did NOT indicate segmentation faults in this code.
The strangest thing is the segmentation fault happens sometimes (very rarely) and NOT every time!
Maybe this is not a good question, but I am very confused about this error.

Comment: Maybe your heap is corrupt.

Comment: What does it precisely mean? I thought it happens only with delete operator

Comment: A corrupt heap can cause a crash on the new.

Comment: Yeah, I see. What do you advise?

Comment: Is it possible that this code is in a member function that you invoke on a pointer which due to some error causes could be nullptr from time to time ?

Comment: I say the bug is not in the code you have provided so its hard to give advice. Although @Christophe has a good point.

Comment: @Christophe , this code is called only in the QMainWindow's constuctor and there are no nullptr...
Furthermore, it's not dereferences

Comment: It's really strange it happens sometimes

Comment: If the application works on os x or Linux, run it in valgrind

Comment: Please post some more of the surrounding code

Comment: I'm workin on linux. I'll try valgrind in a few hours.

Comment: @Frank Osterfeld, I have been trying for two hours with valgrind but(unfortunately) it works every time without segm fault...

Comment: and no warnings about invalid read/writes?

Comment: Valgrind said these(--leak-check=yes) : http://pastebin.com/HtLz547B
So i tried with this option: --track-origins=yes and this is the result: http://pastebin.com/cTTNaHPZ

Comment: I think the problem is I allocate memory but it is not initialized.

Answer (score 1):

You are not calling the `QWidget` constructor in your constructor (I'm assuming `QWidget` is the superclass of `QWidget_add_travel`). Because the superclass's constructor is not called, the data allocated on the heap for your widget is in an *undefined* *state*, i.e. sooner or later something breaks.

Here's a fixed version:

```
QWidget_add_travel::QWidget_add_travel(QWidget *parent) 
        : QWidget(parent), via_l(new QVBoxLayout(this))
{
    build();
}
```

I also took the liberty of simplifying your layout construction by passing `this` to the layout constructor.

Comment: No, this is not the solution because originally my code was like you said.

Comment: @CodeBott Then you should provide a minimal but **complete** example that reproduces the segfault in order to get helped.

Comment: @Murphy this is the example. Segm fault happens exactly when this code run. Furthermore QDebugger point to this code

Comment: @CodeBott It is **not complete**, as others are pointing out, too. You can't copy it into an empty project, compile and run it. Please read [mcve].

Comment: Please note the `: QWidget(parent)` call in the constructor. This *does* differ from the code provided.

Comment: @Murphy I know that you can't, but it's not possibile because all this stuff depends on much more things. I've already read mvce.

Comment: Please add some more of the surrounding code. For example, we don't know if `setBagWid` a function or variable, nor what your classes inherit.

Comment: @JonHarper - even without direct call of base class constructor it will be called. Read the standard

Comment: `QWidget` does not have a constructor taking no arguments, i.e. it can't be default-constructed.

Comment: @JonHarper Yes, it can, because the parent defaults to `NULL`: `QWidget::QWidget ( QWidget * parent = 0, Qt::WindowFlags f = 0 )`

Comment: I didn't realize that it wasn't `explicit`. Good to know. Thanks.

Comment: A controversy: why people give me negative ratings in this question? Why this answer, that is WRONG, has a positive ratings?